# TypeScript Unit testing tools?

Tags: unit-tests

What are unit testing tools used when we code typescript.

What is the best and most efficient?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12695934/unittesting-in-typescript

Comment: Also tsUnit https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit

Comment: Thank you, I read this answer and also about tsUnit. Can you give me hint if tsUnit will be a good choice? :)

Answer (score 0):

In my search to unit-test in TypeScript I found [The Intern](https://theintern.github.io/) most interesting as you can also write the tests in actual TypeScript instead of JavaScript. I most say that I haven't really used it in production, just some small experiments as proof of concept.

Here is an article explaining how to use it combined with TypeScript: https://www.sitepen.com/blog/2015/03/24/testing-typescript-with-intern/

Looks pretty promising when you are using TypeScript and you are looking for a unit-testing setup that supports source maps.

Example test:

```js
import registerSuite = require('intern!object');
import assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
// Assume that we now have a version of our model in TypeScript:
import SimpleTodoModel = require('todo/model/SimpleTodoModel');

registerSuite({
    name: 'SimpleTodoModel',
    // Assume we have a promises interface defined
    'default data'() {
        var emptyModel = new SimpleTodoModel(),
            id:string = emptyModel.get('id'),
            length:number = emptyModel.get('todos').length,
            incomplete:number = emptyModel.get('incomplete'),
            complete:number = emptyModel.get('complete');
        assert.strictEqual(id, 'todos-dojo',
                    'Id should default to "todos-dojo"');
        assert.strictEqual(length, 0,
                    'Todos array should default to an empty array.');
        assert.strictEqual(incomplete, 0,
                    'Incomplete count should default to 0.');
        assert.strictEqual(complete, 0,
                    'Incomplete count should default to 0.');
    }
});
```